# The argument is entered as a list (ie. [4,5,6]). But how can I get the output as a list and not just integers

Tags: python, list

The output I was getting was just integers (ie. 2,6,9). Desired output was a list (ie. [2,6,9] ).

```
def multiplyNums(aList):
    for (i,j) in enumerate(aList):
        newList = []
        if i < (len(aList)-1):
            newList = (aList[i] * aList[i+1])
            x = print(newList,end=',')
        else:
            newList = (aList[i] * aList[i])
            x = print(newList)
    return x
```

Comment: `x = print(...)`? When did `print` start to have a return value?

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the output you get now, and the output you want instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you explain in English what you are trying to do? Be very specific about every single step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it that you would like to produce a list which contains the value of each entry multiplied by the following value (and the last value squared)?

ie.  [2,3,4] -> [2*3, 3*4, 4*4]  ?

If so then I think you should probably do:

```
def multiplyNums(aList):
    newList = []
    for (i,j) in enumerate(aList):
        if i < (len(aList)-1):
          newList.append(aList[i] * aList[i+1])
        else:
          newList.append(aList[i] * aList[i])
    return newList


print multiplyNums( [2, 3, 4] )
```

Here is a funny single line list comprehension:

```
def multiplyNums(a):
    return [x[0]*x[1] for x in zip(a,a[1:]+[a[-1]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to do this would be :

```
def multiplySuccessor(aList):
    newList = []
    for i in range(len(aList)-1):
        newList.append(aList[i] * aList[i+1])
    newList.append(aList[len(aList)-1]**2)
    return newList
```